# How can I set a default value on a Dynamic EnumProperty?

Tags: python, properties

I am trying to fix a bug in the Animation Nodes addon.

The [loop nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation-nodes/blob/25dd4c9cb16af0c25430b12bf52e9fff01108fff/nodes/system/mn_loop_caller.py) has a dynamic EnumProperty and I need to select a default value. But only when the EnumProperty contains Items.

For that I need to know what the value of default is when I don't give it a value. I thought it was an empty string

```
selectedLoop = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    items=getStartLoopNodeItems,
    name="Selected Loop",
    default="",
    update=updateActiveL)
```

but this does not have the same behaviour as if I left out the default parameter

```
selectedLoop = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    items=getStartLoopNodeItems,
    name="Selected Loop",
    update=updateActiveL)
```

Does anyone know what I have to pass to default in order to have the same behaviour?

---

**EDIT:** I discovered that when I add the default parameter the EnumProperty is not created apparently because when I try to add it to the layout later it gives me this error:

```
rna_uiItemR: property not found: mn_LoopCallerNode.selectedLoop
/home/mathieu/.config/blender/2.73/scripts/addons/animation-nodes/nodes/system/mn_loop_caller.py:66
```

Comment: is it just   None ?

Comment: I just tried that after posting my question, but it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: it could be "NONE" as the getStartLoopNodeItems() will add this if it's empty

Comment: Tried but got the same result again.

Comment: items[0][0] if that is acceptable, or you can force the getStartLoopNoodeItems() to add the empty item in any case and put it as default

Comment: That's weird.. I did what you proposed (forcing getStartLoopNoodeItems() to add the empty) but it doesn't work.. It should though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21512/discussion-between-chebhou-and-mathieu-david).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no default when `items` is a function (you'll get an error if you try to specify it).

I'll update the doc, this info is missing currently…

Note even with 'static' enums, not specifying the default is not the same as giving `""` or `None`, currently. Not very pythonic, but a consequence of our current C <-> python code.

Comment: Ow.. well that sucks. I figured it could be a problem caused by the internal implementation. But now I know for sure :) Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Committed ['fix' for that](https://developer.blender.org/rBfff8a519b85da), now it will be possible to pass 'None' as default and get exact same behavior as if not specifying any default (and updated doc, too).

Comment: That is great ! Any chance for a possibility to give a default when items are created with a function? Anyway I'm very grateful for your answers, without you I would have gone mad at searching for a fix ;)

Comment: Eh, well, not really… This would have to be a callback too, way overkill imho. Note however that, since, when no default is specified, item with '0' value is used, you are kind of able to control what's default item from `items` function.

Comment: Perfect, it is not the easiest way but it will do. Many thanks! I really appreciate your time :)

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Because it seems that internally the EnumProperty is just keeping the index of the selected Item. So if I change the order of the list the stored index is not the correct value anymore. Does that make sense what I say?

Comment: Not sure I follow you, if you return five elements tuples `(identifier, name, description, icon, number)`, the fith one is the (internal, C/property) value of each choice. It's that value which is kept by enum prop, and it does not need to match the order of the items (it just happens to do so by default, because most of the time there is no need for something more precisely controlled).

Comment: Well in the function that generates the list passed to items I do the following: I append every element to the list except the active one, I prepend this one. So active element gets index 0 and is being used as default. I have also an update function that updates the active element when it you change it via de dropdown list. Imagine ```El1 - El2 - El3``` element 1 is active. I click El2. The order changes ```El2 - El1 - El3``` The active element is El2 but the dropdown shows El1. That's why I assumed that the index was stored internally. Do you understand what I mean? :)

Comment: Yes, but again, this is not the *index* (i.e. position) of the item which is stored, it’s its *value* (which *by default* matches its index, if you do not specify it).

Comment: Ok I understand, I did not specify it. I will try and see what happens when I do :)